MemoryError() when running Celery with Redis
When I'm running the below celery task using the ExportCsv crud API I'm getting a memory error.
@celery.task()
def download_csv():
    timestamp = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')
    file_name = f"service_requests_{timestamp}.csv"
    file_path = os.path.join(current_app.config['EXPORT_FOLDER'], file_name)

    service_requests = ServiceRequest.query.filter_by(service_status="closed").all()

    with open(file_path, mode='w', newline='') as csvfile:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        csv_writer.writerow([
            "Service ID",
            "Customer ID",
            "Professional ID",
            "Date of Request",
            "Date of Completion",
            "Remarks"
        ])
        for request in service_requests:
            csv_writer.writerow([
                request.service_id,
                request.customer_id,
                request.professional_id,
                request.date_of_request.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
                request.date_of_completion.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') if request.date_of_completion else None,
                request.rating or "No remarks"
            ])

    print(f"CSV export completed. File saved at {file_path}")

    return file_path

Below is the API I'm calling for running this celery task.
class ExportCsv(Resource):
    # @auth_token_required
    # @roles_required('admin')
    def post(self):
        task = download_csv.delay()
        return make_response(jsonify({'message': 'Task has been triggered', 'task_id': task.id}),200)
    
    def get(self, task_id):
        res = AsyncResult(task_id, app=celery)
        if res.ready():
            file_path = res.result
            return send_file(file_path, as_attachment=True, mimetype='text/csv')
        return make_response(jsonify({'message': 'Task still running'}), 400)

When I imported the download_csv task into my main.py file and ran it directly from there it works fine but the problem lies in the celery. Also ive figued out that the error comes when it runs the below line in the celery task.
service_requests = ServiceRequest.query.filter_by(service_status="closed").all()
Can someone please help me to solve this issue?
